# Date/Datetime not working properly in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a stock portfolio dashboard using Dash and Plotly. I was able to successfully plot a line graph using the go.Scatter method and am now unsuccessfully trying to plot a similar graph with a callback function. Unfortunately, the x-axis does not seem to take kindly to the datetime format of my x-axis values but neither does it accept it when I recast the values as strings. I'm using exactly the same dataframe as the one that works when creating a simple line graph without the callback function.
Here's a sample of my data:

| Date | Value | Asset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 1.00 | a |
| 2021-02 | 1.10 | a |
| 2021-03 | 1.05 | a |
| 2021-04 | 1.12 | a |

And here's my code:

```
app = dash.Dash()
date_options = []
for date in df['Date'].unique():
    date_options.append({'label':str(date),'value':date})

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='date-picker',options=date_options,value=df['Date'].min())
])

@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('date-picker', 'value')])
def update_figure(selected_date):
    filtered_df = df[df['Date'] >= selected_date]
    traces = []
    for Asset in filtered_df['Asset'].unique():
        df_by_asset = filtered_df[filtered_df['Asset'] == Asset]
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            x=df_by_asset['Date'],
            y=df_by_asset['Value'],
            mode='markers',
            marker={'size': 15},
            name=Asset
        ))

    return {
        'data': traces,
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'Date'},
            yaxis={'title': 'Portfolio Value'},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

My output looks the following:
[image]

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I can't reproduce it with what you shared, seemed to work fine when I tested it.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Hey. I just updated my post to show what my dashboard looks like. Literally nothing is showing up, and the x and y axis are generic.

Comment: when testing the app run with `debug=True`. That will probably give a helpful error.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden thanks for that pointer, very good to know :). I had a small mistake with a column name, so now it shows up on the graph but I'm now getting the following error message: 
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int
The date column is of dtype=datetime64[ns] so I'm not really sure where the int comes into play :S

Comment: turns out I had to change the type from datetime to str: 
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
Everything seems to work now